# Is there a better way to optimize this query?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

How can I optimize this query? If you need the table structure just let me know, but this is being done as a custom plugin for Vanilla forums

```
SELECT
    G.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            D.DiscussionID,
            A. NAME AS Category,
            D. NAME,
            U. NAME AS USER,
            D.CountComments,
            IFNULL(
                MAX(C.DateInserted),
                D.DateInserted
            ) AS Updated
        FROM
            GDN_Discussion AS D
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GDN_Comment AS C ON D.DiscussionID = C.DiscussionID
        INNER JOIN GDN_Category AS A ON A.CategoryID = D.CategoryID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GDN_User AS U ON U.UserID = D.InsertUserID
        WHERE
            A.CategoryID = '626'
        GROUP BY
            D.DiscussionID
    ) AS G
ORDER BY
    G.Updated DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this query?

Comment: there sure is a way to optimize this question. Can you edit in table structures, and some result data so its a bit easier to figure out what you're doing there.

Comment: Also, I think User is a reserved word. Are you able to actually use that in a query?